# How get which eclipse Version was used to build a project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a project of the year 2012 with the following eclipse files:

```
.settings
.metadata
.classpath
.project
```

With these files, is it possible to know which eclipse version was used to make the project? or Is there any way to know with the files that add eclipse to the project?

Thanks.

Comment: Projects don't normally have a .metadata directory - there is usually just one of these in the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Open the '.metadata' folder, you should find a file with the name - **version.ini**

Open it with any text editor, and you should be able to see the version of the eclipse that was used for the project.

Here's mine:

```
#Mon Apr 09 14:28:40 PDT 2018
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.6.3.v20170301-0400
```